# Leiningen/Clojure is acting weird when I try to connect to Postgresql Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, clojure

I am trying to follow the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application

Everything is going okay until the step where I type

```
(sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
     (sql/create-table :testing [:data :text]))
```

into Leiningen's REPL.  I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occured to cause the driver to fail.  Please report this exception.  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

And then, Leiningen won't even execute the `(exit)` function.  What gives?

Help please, and thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `(System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")`?

Comment: I don't know PostgreSQL, but it looks like that connection string is missing a hostname.

Comment: It might help if you post the full stack trace. Right after the exception occurs, evaluate `(.printStackTrace *e)` and share the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I tried Marko Topolnik's suggestions and they didn't work for me, but this one does:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://localhost/shouter
```

Comment: Fantastic!  This worked!  I'd just about given up on the problem entirely :)

Answer (score 1):

Hans Engel is right. If you connect to `localhost`, use one of these two URL forms:

`jdbc:postgresql:shouter`

`jdbc:postgresql://localhost/shouter`

and by all means, check the [official documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html)